# Display Image & Text for all rows in SQLite table in ListView - java.lang.NullPointerException: null object reference

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I am new to android programming. I am attempting to display all rows from a table in SQLite in a ListView The table is called `teams` and contains `id`, `team_name` and `image`. How ever I am receiving the error below.

```
Process: com.example.android.soccerleaguesapp, PID: 3938
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
     at com.example.android.soccerleaguesapp.TeamImageAdapter.getView(TeamImageAdapter.java:62)
     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15691)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15691)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15691)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15691)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15691)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15691)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15691)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2093)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1850)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1063)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5807)
     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

### getAllTeams method

```
// Getting All Teams
public List < Team > getAllTeams() {
 List < Team > teamList = new ArrayList < Team > ();
 // Select All Query
 String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM teams ORDER BY team_name";

 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
 // looping through all rows and adding to list
 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
  do {
   Team team = new Team();
   team.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
   team.setTeamName(cursor.getString(1));
   team.setPath(cursor.getString(2));
   // Adding team to list
   teamList.add(team);
  } while (cursor.moveToNext());
 }
 // close inserting data from database
 db.close();
 // return team list
 return teamList;

}
```

### Team Class

```
public class Team {
 String team_name, path, league_name;
 int id, league_id;

 public Team(int keyId, String team_name, String path) {
  this.id = keyId;
  this.team_name = team_name;
  this.path = path;
 }

 public Team() {}

 public Team(int keyId) {
  this.id = keyId;

 }

 public int getId() {
  return id;
 }

 public void setId(int keyId) {
  this.id = keyId;
 }

 public int getLeagueId() {
  return league_id;
 }

 public String getTeamName() {
  return team_name;
 }

 public String getLeagueName() {
  return league_name;
 }

 public void setTeamName(String team_name) {
  this.team_name = team_name;
 }

 public void setLeague_id(int league_id) {
  this.league_id = league_id;
 }

 public void setPath(String path) {
  this.path = path;
 }
 public String getPath() {
  return path;
 }
}
```

### TeamImageAdapter class

```
public class TeamImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter < Team > {

  Context context;
  int layoutResourceId;
  ArrayList < Team > data = new ArrayList < Team > ();

  public TeamImageAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList < Team > data) {
   super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
   this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
   this.context = context;
   this.data = data;
  }
  private final int THUMBSIZE = 96;

  private static class ViewHolder {
   ImageView imgIcon;
   TextView teamName;
  }

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View row = convertView;
   ViewHolder holder = null;
   if (row == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.teamName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_img_infor);
    holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_img_icon);
    row.setTag(holder);
   } else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
   }
   Team team = data.get(position);
   holder.teamName.setText(team.getTeamName());
   holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(ThumbnailUtils
    .extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(team.getPath()),
     THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE));
   return row;
  }
```

### DisplayTeam Class

```
public class DisplayTeam extends AppCompatActivity {

 ArrayList < Team > imageArry = new ArrayList < Team > ();
 TeamImageAdapter adapter;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.display_team);

  DatabaseHelper myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

  // Reading all teams from database
  List < Team > team = myDb.getAllTeams();
  for (Team tm: team) {
   String log = "ID:" + tm.getId() + " Team Name: " + tm.getTeamName() + " ,Image: " + tm.getPath();

   // Writing teams to log
   Log.d("Result: ", log);
   //add teams data in arrayList
   imageArry.add(tm);
  }
  adapter = new TeamImageAdapter(this, R.layout.screen_list,
   imageArry);
  ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list_view);
  dataList.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
}
```

I know this is a fairly common error but I have not been able to get my head around where I have went wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly use wrong id when trying to get `TextView` here:

```
holder.teamName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_img_infor);
```

You either don't have a `TextView` element in the layout you inflate or you don't have an element with such id at all (which is very doubtful since your IDE would hint you that).

Answer (score 1):

Your TextView instance is `null`. 
This may be due to incorrect id or mismatch in layout.

Also why not use [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)